# Open Edx E-Commerce Problems

Tags: openedx

When I tried the add new course in e-commerce part. I took this error.

--> Exception: Failed to publish commerce data for course-v1:TEST to LMS.

I have no idea what is the problem here. I haven't found the solution. If you know what is the problem please could you tell me?

Comment: Its better to check LMS errors also. If I'm not wrong this thing can happen due to several reasons. "ecommerce_worker" user, waffle switch etc

Comment: Hello @IsankaWijerathne I have checked LMS logs but I didn't find anything about that. Btw I didn't use "ecommerce_worker" user. I am using "admin" user which I changed the staff feature for it. To be honest I couldn't find "ecommerce_worker" password. I checked my-password.yml.